# Calling PowerShell from a batch file fails

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, cmd

When I call following command from the command line, everything works well. But when I put it in a .bat file and call that file, I get the syntax error saying that I'm missing a closing ' at the end of the command.

```
powershell -command "& 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe' status  | ? { $_ -Match '^!\s+(.*)' } | % { & 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe' rm $Matches[1] }"
```

A strange thing that happens when I call it from .bat is that command gets mysteriously changed. This is the output of the .bat file:

```
C:\workspace>powershell -command "& 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe' status  | ? { $
_ -Match '^!\s+(.*)' } | \Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe' rm $Matches[1] }"
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I'm 100% sure that the content of the .bat file and the command I run manually are the same and that editor (Notepad++) does not perform a stupid thing like breaking the command in two lines.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `} | \Program Files\T` in that section you are missing a single quote. Should be `} | '\Program Files\T` or `} | 'C:\Program Files\T`. The code, in your examples, differs because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character `%` anywhere in a string must be escaped with one more `%` in a batch file to be interpreted as literal character.

```
powershell -command "& 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe' status  | ? { $_ -Match '^!\s+(.*)' } | %% { & 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe' rm $Matches[1] }"
```

works in a batch file. Enter in a command prompt window `help for` or `for /?` and you can read about this requirement for escaping `%` on first help page output.

Comment: I was trying literally every combination of escaping for " and ' and \, but it haven't occurred to me that % requires escaping. Thanks a lot.